# Setting up a ram based VPN

Tags: vpn

Are there any ram based VPN solutions that have options to keep no logs?

I've been looking to set up a portable linux distro, probably Debian, that I'd run from CD without any form of persistence. It would only be used as an throughput vpn by a small team of users. what are my options?

Comment: What's the question here? What's your problem? Just run any Linux server using Live CD and run OpenVPN server on it. CounterMail are already doing it for their gateway servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you boot up a Linux system from a Live CD, the OS will see a local filesystem, but it will be RAM-based. Logs will go to that filesystem, and disappear for good when you switch the power off.

Many existing Linux distributions offer Live CD, e.g. [Debian](http://www.debian.org/CD/live/).

(We say "live CD" but most Live CD can physically reside on USB flash drives, for the same final effect: the medium is used only for reading, not for writing, so any writing which happens at all goes to the RAM and is not kept beyond a power-down or a simple reboot.)

Comment: Does that work for virtualized OS ?

Answer (score 0):

One such VPN also includes a firewall among other things. It is leaf Bering aka uclibc. Boots from a CD and runs in memory. Uses openvpn for the VPN. http://leaf.sourceforge.net/bering-uclibc/

Comment: That software looks unmaintained, which in this context means "probably insecure". The last update on the page linked at the bottom (http://leaf.zetam.org/bering-uclibc/) is dated from 2017.

Comment: If you go to the download page you will see the latest release is 6/10/2019 https://sourceforge.net/projects/leaf/files/Bering-uClibc/6.2.1/

Comment: That's still a few months old. And the fact that I can't find an announcement of that release anywhere is concerning -- especially for software that you'd have to update manually.